# Phone Gap external HTML intergration

Tags: android, ios, html, iframe, cordova

I have built an application using phone gap, and plan to release the app for Apple iOS and Android OS.

The app it's self is fairly simple, and is essentially a glorified HTML website with a few jQuery mobile add-ins for slide functionality etc.

The client have an existing document management system which under request I have amended to be compatible for mobile displays. This being so that users can write notes and save them directly into the system from their phones.

The web document management system is restricted by login and locked out to a select group of static IPs, and because the App is going public, the want the functionality with the database to be limited to the same contraints as the web system...

To all intents and purposes, they want it to be an iframe within the app. So hey, this is what I did... iFrame complete and hey presto works a dream, oh wait, non of the form features work. I can't file upload or anything like this :/

So I tried using  but no such luck here :/ same issues.

Over the weekend I looked into http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_cordova-webview_android.md.html but this looks to be completely in the wrong direction.

I've been looking all weekend for iFrame alternatives that will retain functionality, and am still looking as we speak.

***Can I emphasise*** that this functionality works in the web system on Chrome for Android, Android native browser and also iOS's safari browser.

I essentially need a way of creating something like an iframe, but with the functionality of the native browsers :/ = bamboozled...